# Como leer archivo .dat y guardarlo en un array c++

Tags: c++, array

Tengo que leer un archivo que tiene este formato:

> ```
> Id: 23
> Nombre: Roberto
> Apellido: MiApellido
> Id: 24
> Nombre: Roberto2
> Apellido: MiApellido2
> ```

Y tengo que leer ese archivo  poder trabajar con esos datos pero no se cómo leer.

Tengo un struct creado de la siguiente manera:

```
struct Datos {
    int Id;
    string Nombre;
    string Apellido;
};
```

¿Cómo hago para tener esos datos en un array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Básicamente tienes un archivo de texto... y leer un archivo de ese tipo es una de las operaciones más sencillas de realizar en C++.

Con estas sencillas instrucciones lees una línea de un archivo de texto:

```
if (std::ifstream datos{"tu_archivo.dat"})
{
    std::string linea;
    std::getline(datos, linea);
}
```

Como tus datos van de 3 en 3 líneas y cada línea sigue un formato cerrado, podemos leer un dato completo en tu estructura `Datos` de la siguiente manera:

```
if (std::ifstream datos{"tu_archivo.dat"})
{
    std::string linea;
    Datos d;

    std::getline(datos, linea);
    d.Id = std::stoi(linea.substr(4));

    std::getline(datos, linea);
    d.Nombre = linea.substr(8);

    std::getline(datos, linea);
    d.Apellido = linea.substr(10);
}
```

Si quieres almacenarlo en una colección de datos, sólo falta crearla y leer secuencialmente el archivo, te aconsejo separar el proceso de lectura en una función:

```
Datos leer_un_dato_de_archivo(std::ifstream &archivo)
{
    std::string linea;
    Datos d;

    std::getline(archivo, linea);
    d.Id = std::stoi(linea.substr(4));

    std::getline(archivo, linea);
    d.Nombre = linea.substr(8);

    std::getline(archivo, linea);
    d.Apellido = linea.substr(10);

    return d;
}
```

De esta manera puedes hacer la llamada a la función en un bucle e ir rellenando:

```
int main()
{    
    std::vector<Datos> d;

    if (std::ifstream datos{"tu_archivo.dat"})
    {
        while (datos)
        {
            d.push_back(leer_un_dato_de_archivo(datos));
        }
     }

    return 0;
}
```

Piensa que este código de ejemplo no tiene en cuneta que los datos de entrada no sigan el formato o que existan entradas incompletas.

Answer (score 2):

En su mayoría se pueden leer los datos de un archivo como datos normales. En tu caso la única diferencia será que tendrás que saltarte las etiquetas de termino que vas a leer.
Para poder saltar efectivamente sirve darse cuenta de que todas las etiquetas (Id, Nombre, Apellido) terminan con un espacio justo antes del dato que quieres leer. Podremos saltarnos dichas etiquetas usando la función ignore con un número límite como primer argumento y un carácter espacio como segundo.

Otro problema a enfrentar es si el número de elementos que se van a leer es fijo desde un inicio o puede cambiar en cada ejecución. Dado que no especificas cual es tu caso en el enunciado asumiré por el momento que ya conoces el número de antemano. Si asumimos que la cantidad de elementos es, por ejemplo, dos, el código para leer los dos datos a un arreglo sería el siguiente:

```
Datos arreglo[2];
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    archivo.ignore(100, ' '); // Salta "Id: "
    archivo >> arreglo[i].Id; // Lee el Id del elemento i

    archivo.ignore(100, ' '); // Salta "Nombre: "
    getline(archivo, arreglo[i].Nombre); // Lee el nombre del elemento i

    archivo.ignore(100, ' '); // Salta "Apellido: "
    getline(archivo, arreglo[i].Apellido); // Lee el apellido del elemento i
}
```

Comment: Claro, la cantidad ya la conozco, perfecto!